# jQuery query builder - cannot get it to work - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'extendext' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'extendext' of undefined

Have tried all ways to get query builder to work but have been unable to (after 2 tough days) any help would be appreciated

Getting query-builder.standalone.min.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'extendext' of undefined

Shouldn't get this if using standalone version of query builder

My index.html is below:

Thanks in advance and regards
Toby

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <base href="/"></base>
    <link href="https://querybuilder.js.org/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/css/query-builder.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jQuery-QueryBuilder@2.5.2/dist/js/query-builder.standalone.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var rules_basic = {
      condition: 'AND',
      rules: [{
        id: 'price',
        operator: 'less',
        value: 10.25
      }, {
        condition: 'OR',
        rules: [{
          id: 'category',
          operator: 'equal',
          value: 2
        }, {
          id: 'category',
          operator: 'equal',
          value: 1
        }]
      }]
    };

    $('#builder').queryBuilder({
      plugins: ['bt-tooltip-errors'],

      filters: [{
        id: 'name',
        label: 'Name',
        type: 'string'
      }, {
        id: 'category',
        label: 'Category',
        type: 'integer',
        input: 'select',
        values: {
          1: 'Books',
          2: 'Movies',
          3: 'Music',
          4: 'Tools',
          5: 'Goodies',
          6: 'Clothes'
        },
        operators: ['equal', 'not_equal', 'in', 'not_in', 'is_null', 'is_not_null']
      }, {
        id: 'in_stock',
        label: 'In stock',
        type: 'integer',
        input: 'radio',
        values: {
          1: 'Yes',
          0: 'No'
        },
        operators: ['equal']
      }, {
        id: 'price',
        label: 'Price',
        type: 'double',
        validation: {
          min: 0,
          step: 0.01
        }
      }, {
        id: 'id',
        label: 'Identifier',
        type: 'string',
        placeholder: '____-____-____',
        operators: ['equal', 'not_equal'],
        validation: {
          format: /^.{4}-.{4}-.{4}$/
        }
      }],
      rules: rules_basic
    });
    /****************************************************************
                            Triggers and Changers QueryBuilder
    *****************************************************************/

    $('#btn-get').on('click', function() {
      var result = $('#builder').queryBuilder('getRules');
      if (!$.isEmptyObject(result)) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
      }
      else{
        console.log("invalid object :");
      }
      console.log(result);
    });

    $('#btn-reset').on('click', function() {
      $('#builder').queryBuilder('reset');
    });

    $('#btn-set').on('click', function() {
      //$('#builder').queryBuilder('setRules', rules_basic);
      var result = $('#builder').queryBuilder('getRules');
      if (!$.isEmptyObject(result)) {
        rules_basic = result;
      }
    });

    //When rules changed :
    $('#builder').on('getRules.queryBuilder.filter', function(e) {
        //$log.info(e.value);
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="builder"></div>
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="btn-set">Set Rules</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-get">Get Rules</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" id="btn-reset">Reset</button>
</body>
```

Comment: I can see that you're not including jQuery.js in the page, which will be causing a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to not have an error if you add to the page jQuery AND comment out the missing plugin reference.

```js
var rules_basic = {
  condition: 'AND',
  rules: [{
    id: 'price',
    operator: 'less',
    value: 10.25
  }, {
    condition: 'OR',
    rules: [{
      id: 'category',
      operator: 'equal',
      value: 2
    }, {
      id: 'category',
      operator: 'equal',
      value: 1
    }]
  }]
};

$('#builder').queryBuilder({
 // plugins: ['bt-tooltip-errors'], not in the code/ cdn
  filters: [{
    id: 'name',
    label: 'Name',
    type: 'string'
  }, {
    id: 'category',
    label: 'Category',
    type: 'integer',
    input: 'select',
    values: {
      1: 'Books',
      2: 'Movies',
      3: 'Music',
      4: 'Tools',
      5: 'Goodies',
      6: 'Clothes'
    },
    operators: ['equal', 'not_equal', 'in', 'not_in', 'is_null', 'is_not_null']
  }, {
    id: 'in_stock',
    label: 'In stock',
    type: 'integer',
    input: 'radio',
    values: {
      1: 'Yes',
      0: 'No'
    },
    operators: ['equal']
  }, {
    id: 'price',
    label: 'Price',
    type: 'double',
    validation: {
      min: 0,
      step: 0.01
    }
  }, {
    id: 'id',
    label: 'Identifier',
    type: 'string',
    placeholder: '____-____-____',
    operators: ['equal', 'not_equal'],
    validation: {
      format: /^.{4}-.{4}-.{4}$/
    }
  }],
  rules: rules_basic
});


$('#btn-get').on('click', function() {
  var result = $('#builder').queryBuilder('getRules');
  if (!$.isEmptyObject(result)) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
  } else {
 //   console.log("invalid object :");
  }
 // console.log(result);
});

$('#btn-reset').on('click', function() {
  $('#builder').queryBuilder('reset');
});

$('#btn-set').on('click', function() {
  //$('#builder').queryBuilder('setRules', rules_basic);
  var result = $('#builder').queryBuilder('getRules');
  if (!$.isEmptyObject(result)) {
    rules_basic = result;
  }
});

//When rules changed :
$('#builder').on('getRules.queryBuilder.filter', function(e) {
  //$log.info(e.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://querybuilder.js.org/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/css/query-builder.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jQuery-QueryBuilder@2.5.2/dist/js/query-builder.standalone.js"></script>

<div id="builder"></div>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="btn-set">Set Rules</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-get">Get Rules</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" id="btn-reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: These two comments plus https://github.com/mistic100/jQuery-QueryBuilder/issues/527 solved my problem. Many thanks for your help guys. Life savers

Comment: Thanks for the getrules.querybuilder.filter. Life saver! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check This example here in [codepen](https://codepen.io/romeojathu/pen/xxEWmwo)

This is the JavaScript

```
 $(function () {
           

            $('#builder').queryBuilder({
               

                operators: [
                    'equal', 'not_equal', 'is_null',
                    { type: 'contains_any', nb_inputs: 2, multiple: true, apply_to: ['string'] },
                ],

                filters: [{
                    id: 'name',
                    label: 'Name',
                    type: 'string',
                    operators: ['equal', 'not_equal', 'is_null']
                }, {
                    id: 'category',
                    label: 'Category',
                    type: 'integer',
                    input: 'select',
                    values: {
                        1: 'Books',
                        2: 'Movies',
                        3: 'Music',
                        4: 'Tools',
                        5: 'Goodies',
                        6: 'Clothes'
                    },
                    operators: ['equal', 'not_equal', 'contains_any']
                },
                ]
            });
        });
```